# PERL прерывается цикл

Tags: perl

Беру данные из одной таблицы. Там 10 записей получается.
Далее перерабатываю одно значение в каждой строке и это значение подставляю в новый запрос.
Но срабатывает только первая строка. Остальные игнорируются. Т.е. мне нужно получиться все $item c данными из второй таблцы внутри. Но получается только один $item

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM calcdone ORDER BY sort");
my $rvs = $sth->execute();
while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {              
     
     my @newNum = $item->{sel} =~ /\d+/g;
     my $newsel   =join(',', @newNum);  
 
     $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catn WHERE id IN ($newsel)");
     $rvs = $sth->execute();
     while ($pos = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) 
     { 
     push(@pos, $pos);
     }  
     
 $item->{pos}=\@pos;

 push(@items, $item);  
             
    }
```

Причем если убрать второй блок запроса в БД - нормально получаются 10 $item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что вы переписываете $sth в теле цикла, когда готовите саб-запрос. Попробуйте так:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM calcdone ORDER BY sort");
$sth->execute();
while (my $item = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    my @newNum = $item->{sel} =~ /\d+/g;
    my $newsel   =join(',', @newNum);
    my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catn WHERE id IN ($newsel)");
    $sth2->execute();
    while ($pos = $sth2->fetchrow_hashref){
        push(@pos, $pos);
    }
    $item->{pos}=\@pos;
    push(@items, $item);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, милый человек! :)) Я несколько часов просидел с этим. Все работает. Гениально :)